# Get Text from Android Password TextView

Tags: android, passwords, textview

I hope this hasn't been asked yet, since I couldn't find it.  I am attempting to get a user's username and password for an online service.  I created a username TextView and a password TextView.  I'm able to get text out of the username TextView without problems.  However, I can't get anything from the password TextView.  Below is the XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/passcodeQuery"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/passwordHint"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

The problem is, if I run the code

```
TextView passField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_password);
```

then

```
String toastMessage = "Password: " + passField.getText().toString();
```

No matter what I put into the password field, the toast message gives me

```
Password: Password
```

I obviously won't be toasting the users password normally, I am just doing it now because I want to make sure I'm reading the inputs correctly.  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case, as I can't read the password field.  How do you get around that?  Ton's of apps seem to be able to do it.  Is there an easier way to get a password than what I'm doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to Toast like "PassWord: YOUR EDITTEXT VALUE" then use this.

```
EditText passField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

and then use:

```
String toastMessage = "Password: " + passField.getText().toString();
```

Now toast the message.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I have one more question though.

TextView loginField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_username);

EditText passField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     
String toastMessage = loginField.getText().toString() + "\n" + passField.getText().toString();

That works.  Why can I get the Login info from TextView, and the password only from EditText?

Comment: Can you update your layout XML in your post above to show the relevant part for the username. Is it possible that R.id.user_name is the ID of the EditText?

Comment: @that1dev: What you want to print in to the Message ? You should have to Give the specific Id to the respective view. And getText is the method for to get text from EditText and the TextView. And both the thing is different. You can Edit the EditText value at runtime but its not possible for the TextView. If you want to change the Value of the textView then you should have to done coading to do it. Thanks. Keep coading.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
EditText passField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

instead of "user_password"?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the text from the `EditText` and not from the `TextView`

```
EditText passField = (EditText )findViewById(R.id.editText2);    
String toastMessage = "Password: " + passField.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch password from TextView, you have to fetch from EditText

```
EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

Store it in String as

```
String pwd = password.getText().toString();
```

And toast it for own verification

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from EditText not from the TextView.You can set not get.

```
      EditText passField = (EditText )findViewById(R.id.editText2);

      String toastMessage = "Password: " + passField.getText().toString().trim();
```